# Charge: Stripe Object details does not work

Tags: payment-gateway, charge

I've been testing against Stripe Object details with Charge as per what is said in their documents.
Charge:info tag returns only {stripe_description}, but not these:
{stripe_customer} or {stripe_invoice}

Could someone give a helping hand, or am I hitting bugs again?

Thanks in advance.